# Sort list with Kindle tags alphabetically. What are those tags called?

Tags: javascript, alphabetical, kindle

I am trying to sort a list alphabetically.

Can someone please help me figure out what the `mbp:frameset` and `idx:entry` tags are called?

They don't seem to respond to `getElementByTagName`.

Here's the code. I have tried several versions on to make it function:

```js
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
  if (typeof ul == "string")
    ul = document.getElementByTagName("mbp:frameset");

  var lis = ul.getElementByName("french");
  var vals = [];

  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

  vals.sort();

  if (sortDescending)
    vals.reverse();

  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}

window.onload = function() {
  var desc = false;
  document.getElementById("test").onclick = function() {
    sortUnorderedList("list", desc);
    desc = !desc;
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="test" value="Sort List (click again to reverse)" />
<mbp:frameset>
  <idx:entry name="french" scriptable="yes" spell="yes">
    <idx:orth><b>Notion B</b>
    </idx:orth>
    <p>Définition B</p>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
  </idx:entry>
  <idx:entry name="french" scriptable="yes" spell="yes">
    <idx:orth><b>Notion A</b>
    </idx:orth>
    <p>Définition A</p>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
  </idx:entry>
  <idx:entry name="french" scriptable="yes" spell="yes">
    <idx:orth><b>Notion C</b>
    </idx:orth>
    <p>Définition C</p>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
  </idx:entry>
</mbp:frameset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo mistake. `getElementByTagName` should be `getElementsByTagName`. Its missing `s` after `Element`. Also, you can use `querySelector` to fetch by attribute. `[attribute='Value']`.

A pointer. Its a bad practice to use `window.onLoad` or `element.onclick`. You should use `.addEventListener`. Using `onclick=` multiple times will replace previous values. This can cause issues.

```js
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
  if (typeof ul == "string")
    ul = document.getElementsByTagName("mbp:frameset")[0];
  
  var lis = ul.querySelectorAll("[name='french']");
  var vals = [];

  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);

  vals.sort();

  if (sortDescending)
    vals.reverse();

  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var desc = false;
  document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function() {
    sortUnorderedList("list", desc);
    desc = !desc;
    return false;
  });
})
```

```html
<input type="button" id="test" value="Sort List (click again to reverse)" /><br/>
<mbp:frameset>
  <idx:entry name="french" scriptable="yes" spell="yes">
    <idx:orth><b>Notion B</b>
    </idx:orth>
    <p>Définition B</p>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
  </idx:entry>
  <idx:entry name="french" scriptable="yes" spell="yes">
    <idx:orth><b>Notion A</b>
    </idx:orth>
    <p>Définition A</p>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
  </idx:entry>
  <idx:entry name="french" scriptable="yes" spell="yes">
    <idx:orth><b>Notion C</b>
    </idx:orth>
    <p>Définition C</p>
    <br />
    <hr>
    <br />
  </idx:entry>
</mbp:frameset>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! Do you also know how to get a case-insensitive order into this script?

Comment: @jl001 you can parse all value to a common case and then sort it.